# Nav bar menu items overlap existing content on the page

Tags: html, css

I found a good-looking nav and copied it from the Internet. On the page *Angebot.php* there is a form and when I open the nav, the menu items overlap the existing content on the page. I want that the existing content on the page vanishes or gets put in the background, so it doesn’t interrupt the menu items. How can I do it? Is there a solution?

I don’t know if I described it well, but I hope you know what I mean.

[image: nav bar when closed]

[image: Nav bar when opend]

```css
*,
body,
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}


/* Navigation */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1050px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgb(146 161 176 / 15%);
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 62px;
}

.navbar .menu-items {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .nav-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0e2431;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.7rem;
}

.navbar .nav-container a:hover {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-container .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines {
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #0e2431;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar .menu-items {
  padding-top: 120px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-150%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar .menu-items li {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #0e2431;
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.menu-items {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.logo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container nav-container">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
        <div class="hamburger-lines">
          <span class="line line1"></span>
          <span class="line line2"></span>
          <span class="line line3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Navbar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Angebot.php">Angebot</a></li>
          <li><a href="UeberUns.php">Über uns</a></li>
          <li><a href="Kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label for="cpu">CPU (Cores):</label>
    <select id="cpu" name="cpu">
      <option value="5">1 Core - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">2 Cores - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="18">4 Cores - 18 CHF</option>
      <option value="30">8 Cores - 30 CHF</option>
      <option value="45">16 Cores - 45 CHF</option>
    </select>

    <label for="ram">RAM (MB):</label>
    <select id="ram" name="ram">
      <option value="5">512 MB - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">1024 MB - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="20">2048 MB - 20 CHF</option>
      <option value="40">4096 MB - 40 CHF</option>
      <option value="80">8192 MB - 80 CHF</option>
      <option value="160">16384 MB - 160 CHF</option>
      <option value="320">32768 MB - 320 CHF</option>
    </select>
    <label for="ssd">SSD (GB):</label>
    <select id="ssd" name="ssd">
      <option value="5">10 GB - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">20 GB - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="20">40 GB - 20 CHF</option>
      <option value="40">80 GB - 40 CHF</option>
      <option value="120">240 GB - 120 CHF</option>
      <option value="250">500 GB - 250 CHF</option>
      <option value="500">1000 GB - 500 CHF</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a white background on the menu.

```css
.menu-items {
  background: white;
}

*,
body,
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}


/* Navigation */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1050px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgb(146 161 176 / 15%);
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 62px;
}

.navbar .menu-items {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .nav-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0e2431;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.7rem;
}

.navbar .nav-container a:hover {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-container .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines {
  display: block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #0e2431;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-container .hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar .menu-items {
  padding-top: 120px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-150%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar .menu-items li {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #0e2431;
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.menu-items {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.hamburger-lines .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.logo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="container nav-container">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
        <div class="hamburger-lines">
          <span class="line line1"></span>
          <span class="line line2"></span>
          <span class="line line3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Navbar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Angebot.php">Angebot</a></li>
          <li><a href="UeberUns.php">Über uns</a></li>
          <li><a href="Kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label for="cpu">CPU (Cores):</label>
    <select id="cpu" name="cpu">
      <option value="5">1 Core - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">2 Cores - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="18">4 Cores - 18 CHF</option>
      <option value="30">8 Cores - 30 CHF</option>
      <option value="45">16 Cores - 45 CHF</option>
    </select>

    <label for="ram">RAM (MB):</label>
    <select id="ram" name="ram">
      <option value="5">512 MB - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">1024 MB - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="20">2048 MB - 20 CHF</option>
      <option value="40">4096 MB - 40 CHF</option>
      <option value="80">8192 MB - 80 CHF</option>
      <option value="160">16384 MB - 160 CHF</option>
      <option value="320">32768 MB - 320 CHF</option>
    </select>
    <label for="ssd">SSD (GB):</label>
    <select id="ssd" name="ssd">
      <option value="5">10 GB - 5 CHF</option>
      <option value="10">20 GB - 10 CHF</option>
      <option value="20">40 GB - 20 CHF</option>
      <option value="40">80 GB - 40 CHF</option>
      <option value="120">240 GB - 120 CHF</option>
      <option value="250">500 GB - 250 CHF</option>
      <option value="500">1000 GB - 500 CHF</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Bestellen">
  </form>
</body>
```